# R Generalized Method Of Moments Regression Estimation With Instruments

Tags: r, matrix, regression, singular, generalized-method-of-moments

I'm trying to train a regression model using the generalized method of moments in R. I have 3 endogenous regressors that are correlated with 6 things I know to be exogenous.

- My outcome variable is y
- I have 3 endogenous regressors: z1, z2, z1*z2
- I have 6 exogenous instruments: x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6

In order to do the training I set my data up in an data.matrix `dat`. The first column is y, the second column is all 1s, the third through eighth columns are the instruments x1-x6. The 9th through 11th columns are the regressors (z1, z2, and z1*z2).

Then I set my moment conditions as follows:

```
moments <- function(theta, data) {
    y <- as.numeric(data[, 1])
    x <- data.matrix(data[, c(2,3:8)])
    z <- data.matrix(data[, c(2,9,10,11)])
    m <- x * as.vector((y - z %*% theta))
    return(cbind(m))
}
```

and then I try to train my model:

```
gmm_model <- gmm(
  g = moments,
  x = dat,
  t0 = (lm(y ~ z1 + z2 + z1:z2,
           data=dat))$coefficients
)
```

When I run this I get an error:
`model order:  1 singularities in the computation of the projection matrix results are only valid up to model order 0Error in AA %*% t(X) : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments`

The error indicates that the rank of x is not big enough to estimate the coefficients on the variables corresponding to z.

But when I check `Matrix::rankMatrix(dat[,3:8])` tells me my x has rank 5 and `Matrix::rankMatrix(dat[2,9,10,11])` tells me my z has rank 4. Additionally, `rankMatrix(t(x) %*% z )` yields 4. These values seem to be fine for GMM to me. *What am I doing wrong?*

I also tried to use `pgmm` from `plm`, but my data is really just a cross section (not a panel dataset) and I was getting errors for having multiple observations per individual when I tried to use it.

`dat` looks like:

```
     y i x1 x2  x3   x4     x5      x6 z1        z2 z1*z2
[1,] 0 1 31  0 123 0.12 123456 1234567  0 0.2954545     0
[2,] 0 1 44  0 123 0.12 123456 1234567  0 0.1555556     0
[3,] 0 1 31  0 123 0.12 123456 1234567  0 0.2325581     0
[4,] 0 1 47  0 123 0.12 123456 1234567  0 0.2537313     0
[5,] 0 1 33  0 123 0.12 123456 1234567  0 0.1500000     0
[6,] 0 1 49  0 123 0.12 123456 1234567  0 0.2553191     0
```

x1 is an integer in [30-100]
x2 is binary 0,1
x3 takes two values
x4 takes two values
x5 takes two values
x6 takes two values

z1 is binary 0,1
z2 is continuous in [0,1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a number of different things, what worked was dropping x variables until the number of x variables was the rank of the matrix including all of them as columns: it appears `gmm` does not like having **any** singularity in the matrix of exogenous instruments used in the moment conditions. Explicitly, when I changed to this set of moment conditions, the same gmm call worked:

```
moments <- function(theta, data) {
    y <- as.numeric(data[, 1])
    x <- data.matrix(data[, c(2,3,4,5,6)]) # this is rank 5 still
    z <- data.matrix(data[, c(2,9,10,11)]) # rank 4
    m <- x * as.vector((y - z %*% theta))
    return(cbind(m))
}
```